# Modifying a Quickstart app in OpenShift

Tags: git, github, openshift

On OpenShift I used this quickstart application to get MediWiki running successfully:
https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/mediawiki-example/tree/master/.openshift/action_hooks

And here is the procedure I followed:

```
1) Create an account at https://www.openshift.com
2) Create a php application with mysql:
    $ rhc app create mediawiki php-5.3 mysql-5.1 
3) Add this upstream mediawiki repo
    $ cd mediawiki
    $ git remote add upstream -m master git://github.com/openshift-quickstart/mediawiki-example.git
    $ git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
4) Then push the repo upstream
    $ git push
5) That's it, you can now checkout your application at:
    http://mediawiki-$yourlogin.rhcloud.com
6) Default Admin Username: Admin
   Default Password: OpenShiftAdmin
```

Now I want to modify some of the wiki settings by going in and changing the PHP files that control the operation of the wiki.  Unfortunately, I don't understand how OpenShift and git work together on an application that began life as a quickstart, and so I'm at a loss of where to begin.

I assume that, during the setup of the MediaWiki on OpenShift, MediWiki's PHP code files were downloaded from GitHub, and then installed somewhere on the OpenShift server, and then altered to run with a particular database instance.

(1) Is this correct?

(2) How do I download the currently running PHP files onto my desktop?  I obviously do not want them on GitHub, because it will have security information visible.  (There is a way to hide that information, yes, but that is more advanced than I want to go right now, given my primitive skills.)  The rhc client created a directory for this application on my desktop, including a .git subdirectory, but I can't find any source code files in it.

(3) After altering a PHP code file on my desktop, how do I upload it back to the OpenShift server where it will replace the old?  Is it a git command or a rhc command?

(4) Do I have to do anything special to get OpenShift to see the new files and re-start the application?

I have git installed on my desktop machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:
1.)  Yes, just like the WordPress quickstart, the files are downloaded onto the server
2.)  This installation is made to not be managed via git, so you can't really download the files and modify them easily, it is meant to be installed, and then just managed from the web interface
3.)  See instructions below
4.)  See instructions below

Instructions:
If you would like to run a copy of mediawiki that you can manage via git, you would want to create a php/mysql application, then use git to clone the files to your local machine.  Then download a zip or .tar.gz of the files from the media wiki website, and put those files into your git repository, then do a git add & git push.  Then the OpenShift server will deploy the files and restart the server to show the new changes.  You will need to configure your database configuration file before you do the git commit and git push so that the file will be correct when it deploys.  If you do the setup on the server instead, you will over-write your configuration file on the next push.

This old forum post might help with the database configuration part: https://forums.openshift.com/mediawiki-cannot-connect-to-mysql-database

Comment: Very clear, but I have to say: Oy.  I have never done the database setup for MediaWiki using any method other than the pages it shows me in the web browser... and I'm not keen to learn.  So I think I'll have to go elsewhere.  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like we have a quickstart you can use: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/mediawiki-example

Comment: The Quickstart is fabulous.  My problem is after the Quickstart.  I can't figure out how to alter the MediaWiki source code and then, if necessary, commit the changes.  As a specific example, I want to edit a file called LocalSettings.php that is in MediaWiki's top level of source code, and I want to add a line to it that will set the logo for my wiki.  Using the Unix `find` command with -r (recursive) option, I found one copy of LocalSettings.php.  But it sits in a directory where I don't think adding the line will have any effect: `/usr/share/doc/git-1.8.2.1/contrib/mw-to-git/t/install-wiki`

Comment: I tried to edit the file mentioned above, and the system denies permission to save the changes.

Comment: If you want to edit the code you are better off installing it yourself using git.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OpenShift MediaWiki quickstart repo, you can edit the PHP files via SSH.

1. Log into OpenShift. Find your project. Copy and paste the remote access login.
2. Open up your terminal paste the ssh command.
3. `cd /app-root/data/mediawiki-1.19.15/` The install version may be different.
4. Begin modifying (vim?).

I didn't understand where the MediaWiki files were coming from after using the quickstart repo. But yes, they are located on the server. I have the ability to add mediawiki php extensions. It's not the ideal setup for a project, but I have enough access to curl extensions, install them, and config them with LocalSettings.php (LocalSettings.php remains in your project's git repo under `/.openshift/action_hooks/`). That's quickstart for you.